# Atom editor locking git

Tags: git, atom-editor

Whenever I open a project in Atom editor, git throws permission denied whenever I merge branches. Closing atom resolves the issue.

Is it possible to avoid this behavior in Atom?

EDIT:
I am using SourceTree https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I do not see such behavior with Git and Atom. It may be an issue with one of the packages you have for Atom. Can you provide a list of the packages you have installed in Atom?

Comment: I did <code>apm list --packages</code> and only php-twig@4.0.0 was added. I am using sourcetree BTW